# How to check redirected web page address, without downloading it in Python

Tags: python, http, http-headers, urllib2, httplib

For a given url, how can I detect final internet location after HTTP redirects, without downloading final page (e.g. HEAD request.) using python. I am trying to write a mass downloader, my downloading mechanism needs to know internet location of page before downloading it.

### edit

I ended up doing this, I hope this helps other people. I am still open to other methods.

```
import urlparse
import httplib

def getFinalUrl(url):
    "Navigates Through redirections to get final url."
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(parsed.netloc)
    conn.request("HEAD",parsed.path)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    if str(response.status).startswith("3"):
        new_location = [v for k,v in response.getheaders() if k == "location"][0]
        return getFinalUrl(new_location)
    return url
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you to use requests library. It is well coded and actively maintained. Requests can make anything you need like prefetch/

From the Requests' documentation http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/ :

By default, when you make a request, the body of the response is downloaded immediately. You can override this behavior and defer downloading the response body until you access the Response.content attribute with the prefetch parameter:

```
tarball_url = 'https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/tarball/master'
r = requests.get(tarball_url, prefetch=False)
```

At this point only the response headers have been downloaded and the connection remains open, hence allowing us to make content retrieval conditional:

```
if int(r.headers['content-length']) < TOO_LONG:
  content = r.content
  ...
```

You can further control the workflow by use of the `Response.iter_content` and Response.iter_lines methods, or reading from the underlying urllib3 `urllib3.HTTPResponse` at `Response.raw`

Comment: This now is 
`r = requests.get(tarball_url, stream=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`httplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) to send HEAD requests.

Comment: How about getting thorugh redirections. Should I need to do that manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at [python-requests](http://readthedocs.org/docs/requests/en/latest/), which seems to be the new trendy API for HTTP requests, replacing the possibly awkward `httplib2`. (see [Why Not httplib2](http://readthedocs.org/docs/requests/en/latest/community/faq/#why-not-httplib2))

It also has a `head()` method for this.