# Python detecting user login redirection slow

Tags: python, redirect, authentication, python-requests

I am trying to detect whether logging into a web form creates a redirection or not. Right now this process is fairly slow:

```
import urllib, urllib2

def redirection_occurs(user, password, login_page_url ):

    login_data = urllib.urlencode({
        'username':user,
        'password':password
    })

    data = urllib2.urlopen( login_page_url, login_data )

    # Returns true if redirection occurs
    return data.geturl() != login_page_url
```

What makes the whole thing slow is the call to **urllib2.urlopen( login_page_url, login_data )**, is there a way around this? I simply want to detect whether or not a redirection has occurred after a login.

Comment: Is this server code using bottle, flask, tornado, etc -- whats the context?

Comment: No it's a simply a python script using urllib and urllib2 modules. I added them as imports in the code I provided.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be largely answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484473/how-to-check-redirected-web-page-address-without-downloading-it-in-python) although not a perfect repeat question.

nevertheless, use a `heads` request

in python requests its

```
requests.head(url, **kwargs)
```

instead of

```
requests.request(method, url, **kwargs)
```

Using the [urllib2 library use the answers from this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421170/python-head-request-with-urllib2)

Comment: If you were to put this inside a method to check for redirection, how would you do it?

Comment: checking the status for 300 code as in the requests example   str(response.status).startswith("3"):